# Как реализовать простую авторизацию пользователя в приложении на Flask?

Tags: python, flask

```
def login():
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    flash('Login requested for user {}, remember_me={}'.format(
        form.username.data, form.remember_me.data))


    return redirect('/index')
return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Для начала хотелось бы посмотреть, как авторизация пользователя будет работать без самой базы данных пользователей, т.е. проводить проверку при нажатии кнопки "Войти" на совпадение со значением, которое я определил заранее.
Например, я создал условия входа, при котором логин пользователя должен быть таким: "Login". А пароль был таким: "Password"
Буду любезен, если вы объясните эту столь сложноватую(лично для меня) тему.

Answer (score 2):

Общий принцип, по которому работает авторизация в УПРОЩЕННОМ виде:

1. На странице логина принимаем от пользователя логин и пароль.
2. На сервере проверяем их правильность (информация об этом может быть в базе данных, а может быть в глобальной переменной для упрощения).
3. Генерируем авторизационный токен, длинную строку, которую сложно подделать, если никто, кроме клиента и сервера ее не знает. И связываем на сервере этот токен с уникальным именем пользователя.
4. После чего устанавливаем на клиенте cookie, который будет посылаться вместе со всеми следующими запросами.

В следующий раз, когда клиент придет, посмотрим, есть ли у него кука с токеном и если на сервере есть связанный с ней пользователь - значит пользователь авторизован.

В интернете по этому поводу довольно много информации.
[Мега-Учебник Flask](https://habr.com/en/post/222983/) - рекомендую начать прям с первой главы, если по ходу будут возникать вопросы.